# hibernate DTO with a deviant database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am building a spring boot application which uses REST services to deliver content to the front-end

But my DTO does not correspond to my database.
[Here is a diagram of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS9GU.png)
And my DTO should look something like this

```java
public class GlobeEntity extends BaseEntity {
//  for all definition years
    private List<Instance> instances;
    class Instance {
//      CountryInstance.definitionYear
        private String definitionYear;
//      for all countries
        private List<Country> countries;
        class Country {
//          Country.countryId
            String id;
//          Country.externalIdentifier
            String externalIdentifier;
//          CountryInstanceCompatibility.total
            String com;
//          CountryInstanceUtility.total
            String uti;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do with hibernate annotations?

Answer (score 0):

For the DTO, what is turned into JSON when you return that class from a controller depends on your JSON serializer you have configured in Spring. Then you make use of the JSON annotations to have more control over what is returned.
Depending on how you do things, you may just choose to convert between an entity and a DTO, and have a class for each. Although this is a bit annoying because it does add allot of overhead of having more classes and other classes depending on the two, it can be come a real real mess if you use the same class for both DTO and Entity representations when they are very different. For instance if you use a method in your controller, it's not clear wether this is an entity or a DTO. There are many cases when you have a controller you return a response which is not a resource in a database.